# Fresh Magento 2 installation only shows HTML content without styling

Tags: magento, nginx, magento2

I just completed a fresh Magento 2 installation without any errors, but when I go to home page or /admin page I only see HTML content without any styling.

Any idea why? I use the same nginx config for Magento 1 which worked fine.

- PHP 7.0.8
- nginx/1.10.0
- MySQL 5.7.16

**Home page:**

[image: hope page]

**Console errors:**

[image: console errors]

**nginx config:**

```
server {
 root      /var/www/html/magento2/;
 index     index.php;
 server_name    magento2.dev;
 location / {
   index index.html index.php;
   try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
   expires 30d;
 }
 location ~ ^/(app|includes|lib|media/downloadable|pkginfo|report/config.xml|var)/ { internal; }
 location /var/export/ { internal; }
 location /. { return 404; }
 location @handler { rewrite / /index.php; }
 location ~* .php/ { rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last; }
 location ~* .php$ {
   if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
   expires off;
   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
   fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
   include fastcgi_params;
 }
}
```

**EDIT:**

After messing around with it now when I go to /admin page I get this:

*There has been an error processing your request*

*Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.*

*Error log record number: 846002728319*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should deploy static content by running `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`.

I believe that this step is in installation instruction of Magento.

Also you should make sure that your files have correct ownership and permissions so web server can access them. To make sure that everything is correct (if your web server is running as www-data) open your Magento directory in console and type:

```
chown www-data:www-data -R *
```

That should change ownership of all files to web server.

Comment: I already tried that. When I installed Magento 2 at home on Windows it worked fine and I didn't have to type any additional commands, but that was using apache.

Comment: Can you check if files reported as not found actually are not on their place? If they are there, we should look at your nginx configuration.

Comment: In console it shows path e.g. - `magento2.dev/pub/static/version1484211098/_requirejs/frontend/Magento/luma/en_GB/requirejs-config.js`

But I dont have folder named version1484211098 there. Also some of the files don't seem to be there or some of the folders are named differently like en_US not en_GB as (it searches for en_GB in console, because I set location to GB).

Comment: Probably you should try to deploy with specified locale, like this `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB`, try and let me know.

Comment: Didn't change anything. :/

Comment: Can you also check if file pub/static/version1484211098/_requirejs/fronten‌​d/Magento/luma/en_GB‌​/requirejs-config.js is present?

Comment: It is there, but it is `pub/static/_requirejs/fronten‌​d/Magento/l‌​uma/en_GB‌​/requirej‌​s-config.js` without the `version1484211098`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132998/discussion-between-mateusz-wozniak-and-rudolph).